# Why Python "int" cannot be converted into Tensorflow dtype whereas "float" can?

Tags: tensorflow, types

## Question

Why Python `int` cannot be converted into Tensorflow dtype?

- [tf.dtypes.as_dtype](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/as_dtype)

> Converts the given type_value to a DType.

- [More on DTypes](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor#more_on_dtypes)

> TensorFlow converts **Python integers to tf.int32** and Python floating point numbers to tf.float32.

Numpy types and Python `float` can be converted into Tensorflow dtypes, but `int` cause the error. Please help understand why.

```
print("np.float equivalent in TF is %s" % tf.dtypes.as_dtype(np.float))
print("Python float equivalent in TF is %s" % tf.dtypes.as_dtype(float))

# TypeError: Cannot convert value <class 'int'> to a TensorFlow DType. 
print("Python int equivalent in TF is %s" % tf.dtypes.as_dtype(int))
```

```
np.float equivalent in TF is <dtype: 'float32'>
Python float equivalent in TF is <dtype: 'float32'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-d36ebc2109e2> in <module>
      2 print("Python float equivalent in TF is %s" % tf.dtypes.as_dtype(float))
      3 # TypeError: Cannot convert value <class 'int'> to a TensorFlow DType.
----> 4 print("Python int equivalent in TF is %s" % tf.dtypes.as_dtype(int))

~/conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py in as_dtype(type_value)
    647     return _INTERN_TABLE[type_value.as_datatype_enum]
    648 
--> 649   raise TypeError("Cannot convert value %r to a TensorFlow DType." %
    650                   (type_value,))

TypeError: Cannot convert value <class 'int'> to a TensorFlow DType.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function states that:

> A value that can be converted to a tf.DType object. This may currently
> be a tf.DType object, a DataType enum, a string type name, or a
> numpy.dtype.

You can check the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/types.proto):

```
  ...
  // Data types that all computation devices are expected to be
  // capable to support.
  DT_FLOAT = 1;
  DT_DOUBLE = 2;
  DT_INT32 = 3;
  DT_UINT8 = 4;
  DT_INT16 = 5;
  ...
```

It casts to `float32` when you pass `float` but there is no infer for `int`, directly. You need to indicate that you are passing `int32` or whatever.

```
print("Python int equivalent in TF is %s" % tf.dtypes.as_dtype('int32'))
--> Python int equivalent in TF is <dtype: 'int32'>
```

Also:

```
print("Python int equivalent in TF is %s" % tf.dtypes.as_dtype(3)) # order
Python int equivalent in TF is <dtype: 'int32'>
```